# Why is my method not working? react-redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am studying react-redux. First of all, the action of addTodo looks like this.

```js
let nextTodoId = 0;

export const addTodo = (content) => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: {
    id: ++nextTodoId,
    content
  }
});
```

And the component is here

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../redux/actions";

function AddTodoComponent(props) {
  const [inputValue, setInput] = useState("");
  console.log({ addTodo })

  const handleAddTodo = () => {
    console.log(inputValue)
    props.addTodo(inputValue);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button className="add-todo" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(null, { addTodo })(AddTodoComponent);
```

I want to use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps but It's not working.
I thought It will be work if I use destructing object.
But it's not appear in console too.
Am I wrong?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../redux/actions";

function AddTodo({
  allId,
  byId,
  newTodo,
}) {
  const [inputValue, setInput] = useState("");

  const handleAddTodo = () => {
    newTodo(inputValue);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
      <button className="add-todo" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    allId: state.allId,
    byId: state.byId,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    newTodo: () => dispatch(addTodo()),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo);
```

and this is reducer function.

```js
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  allIds: [],
  byIds: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      const { id, content } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: [...state.allIds, id],
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            content,
            completed: false
          }
        }
      };
    }
    case TOGGLE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            ...state.byIds[id],
            completed: !state.byIds[id].completed
          }
        }
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include `store creation` line of code?

Comment: + What did you get when you `console.log(props.addTodo );` this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a bit of playing but I found your problem! (3 problems, actually).

1. Your `addTodo` function is a function which takes the content of the Todo (a `string`) and creates the action.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    newTodo: () => dispatch(addTodo())
  };
};
```

But in your `mapDispatchToProps` function, you are accepting no arguments and calling `addTodo` with no arguments.  So your Todo gets added, but the `content` will always be `undefined`.

Change this to

```
newTodo: (content) => dispatch(addTodo(content))
```

2. In `mapStateToProps` you've got a misnamed property.  You need to change `state.byId` to `state.byIds`.
3. In order to clear the content of the `input`, you need the value of the `input` to be controlled by your `useState`.  Add `value={inputValue}` to the input element.

```
<input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
```

This is a sidenote, but you might want to think about learning typescript and adding annotations to your projects.  There is a bit of a learning curve but the tradeoff is you would be able to catch things like missing arguments and misnamed properties easily.  They can be a real head-scratcher otherwise.